# Spring CrudRepository query with multiple In conditions

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to get data from a dynamodb table using Spring Data, filtering by two fields using In keyword, but it always return an empty result.

I have an entity like:

```java
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "my-table")
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private MyTableKey id;

    private String saleDate;
    private Long sellerId;

    // Some other properties

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    public String getSaleDate() {
        return this.saleDate;
    }

    @DynamoDBRangeKey
    public Long getSellerId() {
        return this.sellerId;
    }
}
```

and my interface for the repository is

```java
@EnableScan
@EnableScanCount
public interface MySalesRepository
        extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, MyTableKey> {

    Page<MyEntity> findById (MyTableKey id, Pageable pageable);

    Page<MyEntity> findAllBySaleDateAndSellerIdIn (List<String> saleDate,
            List<Long> sellerId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I want to get items that have both saleDate in the saleDate list and sellerId in the sellerId list, but I get 0 results.

How can I get the values I want using And and In keywords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
 Page<MyEntity> findAllBySaleDateAndSellerIdIn (List<String> saleDate,
        List<Long> sellerId, Pageable pageable);
```

to this:

```
 Page<MyEntity> findBySaleDateInAndSellerIdIn (List<String> saleDate,
        List<Long> sellerId, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: That worked! I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you!